# Center Align Span in Div

Tags: html, css

I have this problem where Im trying to center a div with several spans of alternating texts of various lengths.

I have tried everything I could find, but the problem persists. Please, can anyone look into my css for what Im doing wrong?
Heres the link to the website: [www.ultimatexp.com](http://www.ultimatexp.com), I need to center align the changing header: We are exclusive, We are exciting, We are effective, We are entertainer asia.

Thank you!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Just use display:block and then width:100% in .slidingHorizontal span{} and your issue will be resolved.

Comment: I did ask a question with the code earlier, but did not get any relevant answers. I thought maybe theres something else conflicting with that code I dont know about

Answer (score 0):

Use `width :100%;display:block` in your span styles. or either try setting the parent div's text-align property containing the spans as `text-align:center`

Comment: well do you know you can't set width of span until span has display block element so do mention that..and width:100% wont solve the issue..

Comment: well i understand that i shouldn't treat a span as a 100% width block element, it removes the purpose of using a span but it solves the issue. I deally the parent div property of text-align should be set to center

Comment: well your answer is half..you should also mention that use display:block so span will get width and then it will work..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `display:block` us `display:inline-block` for span, then add `text-align:center`